# Mocking no ssl installed

Tags: python, unit-testing, ssl

I am trying to test the compatibility wrapper for library against the possibility that Python was compiled without SSL support.

The problem is that this is detected using the following statement.

```
try:
    import ssl
except ImportError:
    ssl = None
```

How would I go about mocking this safely when removing the ssl import, before the compatibility file is even loaded (or reloaded)? Without disrupting all the other tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign Mock() to the ssl module:

```
import sys
sys.modules['ssl'] = Mock()
```

Before running the code where ssl gets imported.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the behavior I wanted by first saving the module as a local variable, then setting the ssl module in sys.modules to `None` and reloading the file we are testing.

Once the test is complete I simply restore the the ssl module in sys.modules and again reload the file I am testing.

```
# Module we will be testing.
import my_package

def test_ssl_module_not_available(self):
    # Save the module we are going to modify.
    restore_module = sys.modules['ssl']
    try:
        # Set ssl import as None.
        sys.modules['ssl'] = None

        # Reload the code referencing the ssl module.
        imp.reload(my_package.compatibility)

        # Perform the tests.
        self.assertIsNone(compatibility.ssl)
        self.assertIsNone(compatibility.DEFAULT_SSL_VERSION)
        self.assertFalse(compatibility.SSL_SUPPORTED)
        self.assertFalse(compatibility.SSL_CERT_MAP)
        self.assertFalse(compatibility.SSL_VERSIONS)
    finally:
        # Restore the ssl module.
        sys.modules['ssl'] = restore_module
        imp.reload(compatibility)
```